# Template not displaying collection when modal is open

Tags: javascript, meteor

Every time I load the bootbox.js modal the collections displayed in the template behind it vanish. See the pictures for clarity.

Before the the modal is clicked

https://gyazo.com/b00903331bcc690e98888a5b2ad3e486

While the modal is open the collections in the background vanish and will only comeback once you refresh the buy page example:

https://gyazo.com/a36d0e8df55bc2d5b63a5a04b92efb03

The orders table template helper code

```
Template.ordersTable.helpers({
    orders : function () {
        var orderType = Session.get('currentOrderTemplate');
        //if order type == 2 then the active tab has been selected.

        if(orderType == 3) {
            return OrderList.find({createdBy : Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
        } else {
            return OrderList.find({orderType : orderType}).fetch();
        }
    }
});
```

Now, when I do the same thing on the active orders tab it works as I wanted. The collections are displayed in the background and update when the form is submitted.

```
Template.activeOrderTable.helpers({
    activeOrders : function () {
        return OrderList.find().fetch();
    }
    });
```

Completely forgot about bootbox code.

```
Template.loggedIn.events({
    "click a" : function (event) {
        var orderType = $(event.target).attr('data-order-type');
        Session.set('currentOrderTemplate', orderType);
    },
    "click #createOrder" : function (event) {
        bootbox.dialog({
            title : 'Create Order',
            message : "<div id='dialogNode'></div>"
        });
        Blaze.render(Template.createOrderForm, $("#dialogNode")[0]);
    }
});
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would need to see your bootbox code as well. Your helpers look fine. Is anything happening to your publication or subscription as part of the bootbox?

Comment: I completely forgot the bootbox code. I've added it now.

Comment: Does your *createOrderForm* template have any helpers? Do both possible queries in the *ordersTable* helpers return documents? Can't tell what the value of *orderType* might be.

Comment: Thanks for responding Michel, i've uploaded the code to github. https://github.com/cloggy45/Rust-Merchant-Exchange/tree/development/Rust-Merchant-Exchange

Comment: Are you sure that's the right repo? [I can't find a reference to bootbox](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bootbox+user%3Acloggy45&type=Code&ref=searchresults) in any of your repos.

Comment: Are you using iron-router? If so maybe it's a subscription issue. If so please post that code.